# glBufferSubData causes unhandled exception: 0xC0000005

Tags: c++, opengl-4

I am trying to make a mesh class using a vao and a vbo.

First I create vectors to hold the data to be buffered:

```
std::vector<GLfloat> vertices;
std::vector<GLfloat> normals;
std::vector<GLfloat> texCoords;
std::vector<GLushort> indices;
```

I store data from a file and then I create the buffers:

```
// Vertex array
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

// Vertex buffer
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

// Index buffer
glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
```

I try to fill the buffers like this:

```
// Reserve space on the GPU (3 GLfloats per vertex, 3 per normal and 2 per texCoord)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// Load data to the GPU
// Insert vertices at the beginning of the buffer
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, vertices.size()*3*sizeof(GLfloat), &vertices);
// Insert normals behind vertices
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*3*sizeof(GLfloat), normals.size()*3*sizeof(GLfloat), &normals);
// Insert texCoords behind normals
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (vertices.size() + normals.size())*3*sizeof(GLfloat), texCoords.size()*2*sizeof(GLfloat), &texCoords);

// Load the index buffer
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size()*3*sizeof(GLushort), &indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

It breaks when I try to buffer the normal data:

```
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*3*sizeof(GLfloat), normals.size()*3*sizeof(GLfloat), &normals);
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x699CEF38 (nvoglv32.dll) in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x05C34000.
```

I have been searching for a while now but I still haven't found a solution. Any information regarding any mistakes I have made are very welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glaring mistake is this:

`glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, vertices.size()*3*sizeof(GLfloat), &vertices);`

To get the data within the vector, you pass the address of the first element, not a pointer to the vector:

`glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, NULL, vertices.size()*3*sizeof(GLfloat), &vertices[0]);`

You make the same error in the other lines that call `glBufferSubData`, including the line where it finally breaks down where you are using the `normals` vector.

Also, the vector has to be non-empty before using `&vertices[0]`, or if using C++11, you can use the `vertices.data()` function instead of `&vertices[0]`.

Comment: Both changing it to `&vertices[0]` or `vertices.data()` gives me exactly the same error. Also, I thought that a pointer is automatically the pointer to the first item of the array. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @Hans The bottom line is that what I pointed out *is* a problem.  I hope you realize that and not change your code back to the way it was.  And no, you were pointing to the vector `object`, not the data that the vector is addressing.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks. The texCoords vector was empty and I passed in a pointer to a vector instead of the address of the first elment.